# Trying to use curve_fit to fit histogram (binned data) with a gaussian to get optimized mean, std

Tags: python, histogram, gaussian

Another gaussian fit question, and while there are many helpful tutorials/answers, none quite seem to address my problem. I'm trying to find the gaussian fit to binned data (that runs from 70-150, 100 total data points). I'm new at this, so apologies if there are any bug.

Right now, the code is throwing an error for `x_fit` and `y_fit`, and I have no idea why.

The error is an "invalid syntax" error, and parentheses on `popt` and `pcov` don't seem to make a difference.

Can't seem to troubleshoot the rest of the code until I figure that out, but if anyone has suggestions for how to optimize a gaussian fit to binned data, that would be really helpful.

Thanks!

```
import pylab as py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#grabs data from csv - just a list of numbers
#gadata=np.genfromtxt('gaussian-lab1.csv', autostrip=True)

#grabs initial mean/std values from data
m1 = gadata.mean()
s1 = gadata.std()

def gaus(x, a, x0, sigma):
    return a * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / (2 * sigma ** 2))

data = py.hist(gadata, bins=10)
histx = [0.5 * data[1][i] + data[1][i + 1] for i in xrange(10)]
histy = data[0]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaus, histx, histy, p0=(1, m1, s1,))
x_fit = py.linspace(histx[0], histx[-1], 10)
y_fit = gaus(x_fit, *popt)
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, color='r')

#plots histogram
plt.hist(gadata, 10, normed=True)

#plots a gaussian with mean/std that matches data.. but want optimized
#fit1 = ss.norm(loc=m1, scale=s1)
#plt.plot(x1, histo.pdf(x1), 'r-', lw=2)
```

Comment: What is the error you get? In the code above you are lacking a parenthesis on the `popt, pcov = ...` line

Comment: @deinonychusaur xfit/yfit give an "invalid syntax" error & parenthesis on popt, pcov don't seem to make a difference

Comment: Also, in your gaus method curve_fit could send a negative sigma, which (if my brain is not lacking coffee) should be invalid. That could be fixed by adding `sigma = np.log(sigma)` in the method and a `popt[2] = np.power(np.e, popt[2])` after solution has been optained.

Comment: Can you add a sample data sufficient to reproduce your problem?

Comment: You have two data `gadata` and `podata`... it's not that you happened to change their names?

Comment: @deinonychusaur I did switch the two, wow, yikes. However, the line still doesn't show up on the plot?

Comment: You get an error or just no line? If line doesn't show, maybe try `plt.show()` after the `plt.hist` if you are running interactive to be sure it's not just a case of updating the plot?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a minimum least square fit of data to a gaussian function is the same as calculating the mean and the standard deviation of your data. This is true in any dimension. Thus you can save yourself the curve-fit or any other fitting method.

Comment: In my datasets, I sometimes have a datapoint or two that are extreme outliers due to errors in data taking. They can seriously skew the mean and standard deviation. However, I'm fairly certain that if I make a histogram and fit it, the outliers will have much less effect on the mean and standard deviation of the Gaussian I'd fit. Are you saying this is false?

Comment: You can just as well use your outlier exclusion when calculating the mean and standard deviation.